# Return flag 'y' if a column partition value for a date matches with its previous date using sql

Tags: sql, performance, date

Use Case : Daily Flag -  the date ‘2022-07-25’ will be compared with ‘2022-07-24’ if both the dates have same ‘number’ the ‘daily_number_flag’ will be set ‘y’ and if they have same ‘id’ then the ‘daily_id_flag’ will be ‘y’ for the date “2022-07-25”. Similarly, the date “2022-07-24” will be compared with the date “2022-07-23” based on the ‘number’ and ‘id’ the daily flags will be assigned respectively. The same is followed for all the other dates.

I will also have to assign monthly and yearly flags for both number and id.

Monthly flag  - the date ‘2022-07-25’ will be compared with ‘2022-06-25’ if both the dates have same ‘number’ the ‘monthly_number_flag’ will be set ‘y’ and if they have same ‘id’ then the ‘monthly_id_flag’ will be ‘y’ for the date “2022-07-25”. Similarly, the date “2022-07-24” will be compared with the date “2022-06-24” based on the ‘number’ and ‘id’ the monthly flags will be assigned respectively. The same is followed for all the other dates.

Yearly flag  - the date ‘2022-07-25’ will be compared with ‘2021-07-25’ if both the dates have same ‘number’ the ‘yearly_number_flag’ will be set ‘y’ and if they have same ‘id’ then the ‘yearly_id_flag’ will be ‘y’ for the date “2022-07-25”. Similarly, the date “2022-07-24” will be compared with the date “2021-07-24” based on the ‘number’ and ‘id’ the yearly flags will be assigned respectively. The same is followed for all the other dates.

Finally i will have 6 flags within the same table. Three flags for number(daily, monthly, yearly) and Three flags for id(daily, monthly, yearly).

I have done it for daily flag using lag function but this does not seems feasible with monthly and yearly.

```
WITH t1
     AS (SELECT customer_number,
                contract_id,
                time_key_source,
                Lag(time_key_source)
                  OVER(
                    partition BY customer_number
                    ORDER BY time_key_source) AS previous_customer_eff,
                    Lag(time_key_source)
                  OVER(
                    partition BY contract_id
                    ORDER BY time_key_source) AS previous_contract_eff
         FROM  contracts1)
SELECT customer_number,
       contract_id,
       time_key_source,
       CASE
         WHEN previous_customer_eff = Dateadd(d, -1, time_key_source) THEN 'y'
         ELSE 'n'
       END AS daily_customer_flag,
       CASE
         WHEN previous_contract_eff = Dateadd(d, -1, time_key_source) THEN 'y'
         ELSE 'n'
       END AS daily_contract_flag
FROM   t1
ORDER  BY time_key_source DESC;
```

Pre
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atHxz.png)
Post
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEwrt.png)

Comment: Don't you just want to use `dateadd(month, -1, time_key_source)` and `dateadd(year, -1, time_key_source)`? I'm not sure whether the dates should match or whether they should just fall somewhere within the same month/year?

Comment: @shawnt00 The dates should match.. Like you mentioned we tried using dateadd() but we don't want to make use of any loop. Also, if you have a way we can achieve this using dateadd() without any looping condition, please do guide me.

Comment: Just to brief the use case again, lets pick the date '2022-07-25'                                  
case 1: check if the number is present in the previous date i.e. '2022-07-24'. If yes, then assign daily_number_flag to 'y', Similarly, check if the id is present in the previous date i.e. '2022-07-24'. If yes, then assign daily_id_flag to 'y'.

Comment: case 2: check if the number is present in the previous month on the same date i.e. '2022-06-25'. If yes, then assign monthly_number_flag to 'y', Similarly, check if the id is present in the previous month on the same date i.e. '2022-06-25'. If yes, then assign monthly_id_flag to 'y'.

Comment: case 3: check if the number is present in the previous year on the same date i.e. '2021-07-25'. If yes, then assign yearly_number_flag to 'y', Similarly, check if the id is present in the previous year on the same date i.e. '2021-07-25'. If yes, then assign yearly_id_flag to 'y'.   So, 6 flags in total. Any help will be appreciated.   Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know why looping would come into play. Why does `dateadd()` not work.

Comment: @shawnt00 I am new to sql, apologies if I am missing out on anything. There are multiple dates and to compare each date with its previous dates, looping was our first thought. Could this be done using recursive cte? or any other method?

Comment: So you're looking to see if there's a date at any point in the sequence but you can't use `lag()` because you won't be able to look exactly one row backward.

Comment: yes, exactly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have SQL Server give something like this a shot:

```
select *
from t t1 cross apply (
    select distinct
        max(case when t2.time_key_source = dateadd(day,   -1, t1.time_key_source) then 'Y' else 'N' end) over () as one_day_ago,
        max(case when t2.time_key_source = dateadd(month, -1, t1.time_key_source) then 'Y' else 'N' end) over () as one_month_ago,
        max(case when t2.time_key_source = dateadd(year,  -1, t1.time_key_source) then 'Y' else 'N' end) over () as one_year_ago
    from t t2
    where t2.customer_number = t1.customer_number
      -- narrow the search range to the be as small as possible
      and t2.time_key_source >= dateadd(year, -1, t1.time_key_source)
      and t2.time_key_source  < t1.time_key_source
) v
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=69c75b18842c0577cccba4c8262464ae

This had to use `distinct` with the analytic `max` to get around a limitation of SQL Server so I do have some concerns that this might not be the best approach.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. But, like I mentioned earlier we will have one_day_ago, one_month_ago and one_year_ago flag separately for both customer_number and contract_id, so 6 flags in total. Also, I do not want to use distinct in this case, lets say I have 10 records, I just need to assign flags to those 10 records only, irrespective of duplicates being present in either of the columns. Really appreciate the effort you put in, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Count records per id and number. If more than 1 set daily flag to Y

```
with cte_table as (
select 'id001' as id  , '2022-07-25' as Date  , 10 as number union
select 'id001'  , '2022-07-24' , 10 union
select 'id001'  , '2022-07-26' , 10 union
select 'id001'  , '2022-07-25' , 20 union
select 'id001'  , '2022-07-25' , 20
)
, cte_tuplecount as (
select id, number, count(1) as CountOf from cte_table group by id, number
)
select cte_table.id, cte_table.date, cte_table.number
     , case when cte_tuplecount.CountOf > 1 then 'Y' else 'N' end as DailyFlag
  from cte_tuplecount
  inner join cte_table 
  on cte_table.id = cte_tuplecount.id and cte_table.number = cte_tuplecount.number
```

[image: Original Data, After Query]

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution.. There is a change in the use case and i have edited the Question, it would be really helpful if you could help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

[NOTE: I have added an ID column in the table to uniquely identify each record]

@shawnt00 I was able to modify your query a bit and seems like its working. Performing few more tests but thanks for the solution and feel free to review the below query

```
with tab1 as 
(
select *
from contracts1 t1 cross apply (
    select distinct
        max(case when t2.time_key_source = dateadd(day,   -1, t1.time_key_source) then 'Y' else 'N' end) over () as daily_cust_flag,
        max(case when t2.time_key_source = dateadd(month, -1, t1.time_key_source) then 'Y' else 'N' end) over () as monthly_cust_flag,
         max(case when t2.time_key_source = dateadd(year,  -1, t1.time_key_source) then 'Y' else 'N' end) over () as yearly_cust_flag
    from contracts1 t2
    where t2.customer_number = t1.customer_number
) as v1
),
tab2 as 
(
select *
from contracts1 t1 cross apply (
    select distinct
        max(case when t2.time_key_source = dateadd(day,   -1, t1.time_key_source) then 'Y' else 'N' end) over () as daily_contract_flag,
        max(case when t2.time_key_source = dateadd(month, -1, t1.time_key_source) then 'Y' else 'N' end) over () as monthly_contract_flag,
         max(case when t2.time_key_source = dateadd(year,  -1, t1.time_key_source) then 'Y' else 'N' end) over () as yearly_contract_flag
    from contracts1 t2
    where t2.CONTRACT_ID = t1.CONTRACT_ID
) as v2
)

select distinct tab1.customer_number,
tab1.contract_id, 
tab1.time_key_source, 
tab1.daily_cust_flag, tab1.monthly_cust_flag, tab1.yearly_cust_flag,
tab2.daily_contract_flag, tab2.monthly_contract_flag, tab2.yearly_contract_flag
from tab1 inner join tab2 on tab1.ID = tab2.ID order by tab1.TIME_KEY_SOURCE desc;
```